# Finding unassigned range within a range in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, range

[image]

I want to get unassigned ranges from the specified ranges for eg taking record with id 43 is the parent record and I want to get unassigned records like in the image below, records with id 44 and 45 are children of record with id 43

[image]

Comment: Also could you be more descriptive, you say the table shown is the parent. What is the structure of the child, which I assume holds the assigned batch numbers?

Comment: What I have done so far is I can get the parent allocation and assigned ranges but I have not find how to figure out unassigned ranges from these two info  
`SELECT * FROM VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION WHERE PARENT_FK IS NULL AND CHANNEL_FROM_FK = 1 AND ID = 43;

SELECT * FROM VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION WHERE PARENT_FK IS NOT NULL  AND PARENT_FK = 43;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the assumption that Assigned Ranges do not overlap.

## **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5814a/32)**

Basically it consists of four Queries.

- The First Query finds any range of unallocated numbers between the parents specified Start number `Batch_number_from` and the Start number `Batch_number_from` of the first child record ordered by `Batch_number_from`.
- The Second Query finds any ranges of unallocated numbers that lie between child records of a parent.
- The Third Query finds any range of unallocated numbers between the parents specified End number `Batch_number_to` and the End number `Batch_number_to` of the last child record ordered by `Batch_number_from`.
- And lastly the Fourth finds any parent records that do not have corresponding child records and therefore have no allocated numbers.

All the four Queries are brought together using `UNION`

Within the First three queries are two sub queries which are repeated and so could be moved to temporary tables. These are labelled `ChildRnk` and `NextStart`.

`ChildRnk` ranks all child records ordered by `Batch_number_from`.

`NextStart` returns the starting number of the next batch of allocated numbers `Batch_number_from` for any given child (If there is another child listed against that specific parent record).

Hope this helps

For MSSQL:

```
SELECT 
    ChildRnk.Parent,
    Batch_Number_From AS START,
    (START-1) AS [End]
FROM 
    (SELECT
        a.Id AS Id,
        a.parent_fk AS Parent,
        a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
        a.Batch_Number_To AS 'End',
        RANK() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY a.parent_fk ORDER BY a.Batch_Number_From ASC) AS Rnk1
    FROM 
        VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS a
    WHERE 
        a.channel_from_fk = 2) ChildRnk
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
        c.Parent,
        c.START AS NextStart,
        (Rnk1-1) AS Rnk2 
    FROM 
        (SELECT
            b.Id AS Id,
            b.parent_fk AS Parent,
            b.Batch_Number_From AS START,
            b.Batch_Number_To AS 'End',
            RANK() 
                OVER (PARTITION BY b.parent_fk ORDER BY b.Batch_Number_From ASC) AS Rnk1
        FROM 
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS b
        WHERE 
            b.channel_from_fk = 2) c
    WHERE 
        Rnk1 != 1) NextStart
ON 
    ChildRnk.Parent = NextStart.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = Rnk2
LEFT JOIN 
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION
ON 
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION.Id = ChildRnk.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = 1
WHERE 
    Batch_Number_From IS NOT NULL
    AND Batch_Number_From < START

UNION

SELECT 
    ChildRnk.Parent,
    ([End]+1) AS START,
    (NextStart-1) AS [End]
FROM 
    (SELECT
        a.Id AS Id,
        a.parent_fk AS Parent,
        a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
        a.Batch_Number_To AS 'End',
        RANK() 
             OVER (PARTITION BY a.parent_fk ORDER BY a.Batch_Number_From ASC) AS Rnk1
    FROM 
        VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS a
    WHERE 
        a.channel_from_fk = 2) ChildRnk
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
        c.Parent,
        c.START AS NextStart,
        (Rnk1-1) AS Rnk2 
    FROM 
        (SELECT
            b.Id AS Id,
            b.parent_fk AS Parent,
            b.Batch_Number_From AS START,
            b.Batch_Number_To AS 'End',
            RANK() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY b.parent_fk ORDER BY b.Batch_Number_From ASC) AS Rnk1
        FROM 
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS b
        WHERE 
            b.channel_from_fk = 2) c
    WHERE 
        Rnk1 != 1) NextStart
ON 
    ChildRnk.Parent = NextStart.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = Rnk2
LEFT JOIN 
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION
ON 
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION.Id = ChildRnk.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = 1
WHERE 
    NextStart IS NOT NULL
    AND [End] < NextStart

UNION

SELECT 
    ChildRnk.Parent,
    ([End]+1) AS START,
    EndLimit.VeryEnd AS [End]
FROM 
    (SELECT
        a.Id AS Id,
        a.parent_fk AS Parent,
        a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
        a.Batch_Number_To AS 'End',
        RANK() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY a.parent_fk ORDER BY a.Batch_Number_From ASC) AS Rnk1
    FROM 
        VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS a
    WHERE 
        a.channel_from_fk = 2) ChildRnk
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
        c.Parent,
        c.START AS NextStart,
        (Rnk1-1) AS Rnk2 
    FROM 
        (SELECT
            b.Id AS Id,
            b.parent_fk AS Parent,
            b.Batch_Number_From AS START,
            b.Batch_Number_To AS 'End',
            RANK() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY b.parent_fk ORDER BY b.Batch_Number_From ASC) AS Rnk1
        FROM 
             VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS b
        WHERE 
            b.channel_from_fk = 2) c
    WHERE 
        Rnk1 != 1) NextStart
    ON 
        ChildRnk.Parent = NextStart.Parent
        AND Rnk1 = Rnk2
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
        a.Id,
        a.Batch_Number_To AS VeryEnd,
        Rnk2
    FROM 
        VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION a
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            max(ChildRnk.Parent) AS MaxParent,
            max(ChildRnk.Rnk1) AS Rnk2
        FROM 
            (SELECT
                 a.Id AS Id,
                 a.parent_fk AS Parent,
                 a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
                 a.Batch_Number_To AS 'End',
                 RANK() OVER 
                     (PARTITION BY a.parent_fk ORDER BY a.Batch_Number_From ASC) AS Rnk1
            FROM 
                VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS a
            WHERE 
                a.channel_from_fk = 2) ChildRnk
        GROUP BY 
            ChildRnk.Parent) c
    ON 
        c.MaxParent = a.id
    WHERE 
        a.channel_from_fk = 1) EndLimit
ON 
    EndLimit.Id = ChildRnk.Parent
    AND EndLimit.Rnk2 = Rnk1
WHERE 
    EndLimit.VeryEnd IS NOT NULL
    AND [End] < EndLimit.VeryEnd

UNION 

SELECT
    a.id AS Parent,
    a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
    a.Batch_Number_To AS [End]
FROM
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION a
WHERE 
    a.Channel_From_Fk = 1
    And a.id not in 
        (SELECT 
            Parent_Fk 
        FROM 
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION 
        WHERE 
            Channel_From_Fk=2)
```

#### Edit: Script ReWritten for MySql below

## **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5814a/35)**

For MySQL I've had to replace the [Rank()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function with a SubQuery which will achieve the same outcome, as unfortunatley [Rank()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) is not supported in MySQL.

```
SELECT
    ChildRnk.Parent,
    Batch_Number_From AS START,
    (START-1) AS TheEnd
FROM
    (SELECT
        a.Id AS Id,
        a.parent_fk AS Parent,
        a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
        a.Batch_Number_To AS TheEnd,
        Rnk.Rank AS Rnk1
    FROM 
        VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            g1.id,
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            COUNT(*) AS rank
        FROM
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g1
        JOIN
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g2
        ON
            (g2.Batch_Number_From, g2.id) <= (g1.Batch_Number_From, g1.id)
            AND g1.Parent_Fk = g2.Parent_Fk
        GROUP BY
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            g1.Batch_Number_From
        ORDER BY
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            rank) Rnk
    ON
        Rnk.id = a.Id
    WHERE 
        a.channel_from_fk = 2) ChildRnk
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        c.Parent,
        c.START AS NextStart,
        (Rnk1-1) AS Rnk2
    FROM 
        (SELECT
            b.Id AS Id,
            b.parent_fk AS Parent,
            b.Batch_Number_From AS START,
            b.Batch_Number_To AS TheEnd,
            Rnk.Rank AS Rnk1
        FROM 
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS b
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT
                g1.id,
                g1.Parent_Fk,
                COUNT(*) AS rank
            FROM
                VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g1
            JOIN
                VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g2
            ON
                (g2.Batch_Number_From, g2.id) <= (g1.Batch_Number_From, g1.id)
                AND g1.Parent_Fk = g2.Parent_Fk
            GROUP BY
                g1.Parent_Fk,
                g1.Batch_Number_From
            ORDER BY
                g1.Parent_Fk,
                rank) Rnk
        ON
            Rnk.id = b.Id
        WHERE 
            b.channel_from_fk = 2) c
    WHERE Rnk1 != 1) NextStart
ON 
    ChildRnk.Parent = NextStart.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = Rnk2
LEFT JOIN 
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION
ON 
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION.Id = ChildRnk.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = 1
WHERE 
    Batch_Number_From IS NOT NULL
    AND Batch_Number_From < START

UNION

SELECT
    ChildRnk.Parent,
    (TheEnd+1) AS START,
    (NextStart-1) AS TheEnd
FROM
    (SELECT
        a.Id AS Id,
        a.parent_fk AS Parent,
        a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
        a.Batch_Number_To AS TheEnd,
        Rnk.rank AS Rnk1
    FROM 
        VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            g1.id,
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            COUNT(*) AS rank
        FROM
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g1
        JOIN
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g2
        ON
            (g2.Batch_Number_From, g2.id) <= (g1.Batch_Number_From, g1.id)
            AND g1.Parent_Fk = g2.Parent_Fk
        GROUP BY
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            g1.Batch_Number_From
        ORDER BY
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            rank) Rnk
    ON
        Rnk.id = a.Id
    WHERE 
        a.channel_from_fk = 2) ChildRnk
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        c.Parent,
        c.START AS NextStart,
        (Rnk1-1) AS Rnk2
    FROM 
        (SELECT
            b.Id AS Id,
            b.parent_fk AS Parent,
            b.Batch_Number_From AS START,
            b.Batch_Number_To AS TheEnd,
            Rnk.rank AS Rnk1
        FROM 
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS b
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT
                g1.id,
                g1.Parent_Fk,
                COUNT(*) AS rank
            FROM
                VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g1
            JOIN
                VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g2
            ON
                (g2.Batch_Number_From, g2.id) <= (g1.Batch_Number_From, g1.id)
                AND g1.Parent_Fk = g2.Parent_Fk
            GROUP BY
                g1.Parent_Fk,
                g1.Batch_Number_From
            ORDER BY
                g1.Parent_Fk,
                rank) Rnk
        ON
            Rnk.id = b.Id
        WHERE 
            b.channel_from_fk = 2) c
    WHERE 
        Rnk1 != 1) NextStart
ON 
    ChildRnk.Parent = NextStart.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = Rnk2
LEFT JOIN 
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION
ON 
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION.Id = ChildRnk.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = 1
WHERE 
    NextStart IS NOT NULL
    AND TheEnd < NextStart

UNION

SELECT
    ChildRnk.Parent,
    (TheEnd+1) AS START,
    EndLimit.VeryEnd AS TheEnd
FROM
    (SELECT
        a.Id AS Id,
        a.parent_fk AS Parent,
        a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
        a.Batch_Number_To AS TheEnd,
        Rnk.Rank AS Rnk1
    FROM 
        VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            g1.id,
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            COUNT(*) AS rank
        FROM
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g1
        JOIN
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g2
        ON
            (g2.Batch_Number_From, g2.id) <= (g1.Batch_Number_From, g1.id)
            AND g1.Parent_Fk = g2.Parent_Fk
        GROUP BY
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            g1.Batch_Number_From
        ORDER BY
            g1.Parent_Fk,
            rank) Rnk
    ON
        Rnk.id = a.Id
    WHERE 
        a.channel_from_fk = 2) ChildRnk
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        c.Parent,
        c.START AS NextStart,
        (Rnk1-1) AS Rnk2
    FROM 
        (SELECT
            b.Id AS Id,
            b.parent_fk AS Parent,
            b.Batch_Number_From AS START,
            b.Batch_Number_To AS TheEnd,
            Rnk.Rank AS Rnk1
        FROM 
            VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS b
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT
                g1.id,
                g1.Parent_Fk,
                COUNT(*) AS rank
            FROM
                VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g1
            JOIN
               VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g2
            ON
               (g2.Batch_Number_From, g2.id) <= (g1.Batch_Number_From, g1.id)
               AND g1.Parent_Fk = g2.Parent_Fk
            GROUP BY
               g1.Parent_Fk,
               g1.Batch_Number_From
            ORDER BY
               g1.Parent_Fk,
               rank) Rnk
        ON
            Rnk.id = b.Id
        WHERE 
            b.channel_from_fk = 2) c
    WHERE 
        Rnk1 != 1) NextStart
ON 
    ChildRnk.Parent = NextStart.Parent
    AND Rnk1 = Rnk2
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        a.Id,
        a.Batch_Number_To AS VeryEnd,
        Rnk2
    FROM 
        VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION a
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            max(ChildRnk.Parent) AS MaxParent,
            max(ChildRnk.Rnk1) AS Rnk2
        FROM
            (SELECT
                a.Id AS Id,
                a.parent_fk AS Parent,
                a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
                a.Batch_Number_To AS TheEnd,
                Rnk.Rank AS Rnk1
            FROM 
                VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS a
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT
                    g1.id,
                    g1.Parent_Fk,
                    COUNT(*) AS rank
                FROM
                    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g1
                JOIN
                    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION AS g2
                ON
                    (g2.Batch_Number_From, g2.id) <= (g1.Batch_Number_From, g1.id)
                    AND g1.Parent_Fk = g2.Parent_Fk
                GROUP BY
                    g1.Parent_Fk,
                    g1.Batch_Number_From
                ORDER BY
                    g1.Parent_Fk,
                    rank) Rnk
            ON
                Rnk.id = a.Id
            WHERE 
                a.channel_from_fk = 2) ChildRnk
        GROUP BY 
            ChildRnk.Parent) c
    ON 
        c.MaxParent = a.id
    WHERE 
        a.channel_from_fk = 1) EndLimit
ON 
    EndLimit.Id = ChildRnk.Parent
    AND EndLimit.Rnk2 = Rnk1
WHERE 
    EndLimit.VeryEnd IS NOT NULL
    AND TheEnd < EndLimit.VeryEnd

UNION

SELECT
    a.id AS Parent,
    a.Batch_Number_From AS START,
    a.Batch_Number_To AS TheEnd
FROM
    VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION a
WHERE
    a.Channel_From_Fk = 1
    AND a.id NOT IN (SELECT Parent_Fk FROM VOUCHER_BATCH_ALLOCATION WHERE Channel_From_Fk=2)
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: I have tried this and I gives this errors  
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[END]
FROM 
    (SELECT
        a.ID AS Id,
        a.PARENT_FK AS Parent,
     ' at line 4 

 Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[END]
FROM 
    (SELECT
        a.ID AS Id,
        a.PARENT_FK AS Parent,
     ' at line 4

Comment: Hmmm, Yes I see. My script was written for use in MSSQL rather than MySql. I'll have a look to see if it can be amended.

Comment: I've added the amended script for MySql to the above answer. Hope it's of use

Comment: This works fine, I would have spent some months getting this to works.. @DMK

Comment: The script works but could probably be simplified in areas which may make it a) easier to read and b) more efficient. It may be worth adding the code as a post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some opinions. But for the time being it does the job required. Glad it was of use.